# have I thought correctly, $p(x\leq3\cup x>7) $

Tags: calculus, statistics

i) $p(x\leq3\cup x>7$.
i use one of the formula: $p(x\leq3\cup x>7)=p(x\leq3) + p(x>7)-p(x\leq3\cap x>7)$

$p(x\leq3\cap x>7)$=0, because of it's not possible?
the probability that x is less than or equal to 3, $x=[0,1,2,3]$ and x is greater than 7, $(8,\infty)$

is this correct thought?

Comment: Well...you are correct about the set theory part (the intersection is empty so the probability of landing there is $0$).  Of course you haven't told us anything about $x$ so we can't comment on the actual probability.

Comment: To be clear:  you deduce that $x\in \{0,1,2,3\}$, for one part of the calculation, but you haven't told us that $x$ was an integer, nor that it was non-negative.  Also your interval $[7,\infty]$ would appear to include $7$ which seems incorrect.

Comment: Putting a square bracket around $\infty$ also seems incorrect, for this level anyway.  That's perhaps less egregious.

Comment: Correct, it shouldt include 7. But it is a poisson problem,So I find the values through a table. I was more interested if $p(x\leq3\cap x>7)=0$ was correct

Comment: I see that I should not put a bracket

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{x:x\leq3,x \in N\},B=\{x:x>7,x \in N\}$ since $A\cap B= O$ then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) +P(B)$ so yes u are right.